# why email html can't show url image

Tags: html, image, url, gmail, styles

I have an email html design but can't show image in email, I upload image in my drive and copy link of it.

used this code:

```
 <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" style="text-decoration: none;"><img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DHEcyMm0zdVrmO0/view?usp=sharing" width="30" height="31" alt="" style="border: 0; line-height: 100%; outline: 0; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; color: #ffffff;"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a publicly accessible link

try this

```
 <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" style="text-decoration: none;"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3d/Envelope_font_awesome.svg/1024px-Envelope_font_awesome.svg.png" width="30" height="31" alt="" style="border: 0; line-height: 100%; outline: 0; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; color: #ffffff;"></a>
```

Comment: Yes i know this way but i need to use my designed photo

Comment: @manalal-harbi you can try free image hosting websites like https://www.hizliresim.com/ (i tried and it worked)